# Python array_flip analogue or best way to do this?

Tags: python, sorting

Is there array_flip (php) analogue for Python 3.x?

from

```
obj = ['a', 'c', 'b' ]
```

to

```
{'a': 1, 'c':2, 'b': 3}
```

Comment: `{i:j+1 for j,i in enumerate(obj)}`

Comment: What happens when you have two `a`s? Should the lowest index remaing or the new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension along with the `dict` constructor, as follows:

```
>>> obj = [ 'a', 'c', 'b' ]
>>> dict((x, i + 1) for i, x in enumerate(obj))
{'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'b': 3}
```

As noted in the comments, you can also use a simple dict comprehension:

```
>>> { x: i + 1 for i, x in enumerate(obj) }
{'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'b': 3}
```

Comment: you may use dict_comprehension instead of list_comprehension

Comment: `enumerate` has a `start` parameter: `{x:i for i,x in enumerate(obj, start=1)}`.

Comment: Thanks! Nice and simple )